Select values from a parametrized family
Suppose I have a following list of expressions of the following form: {ConditionalExpression[Pi*n+Pi/2, Element[n, Integers]], ConditionalExpression[2*n, Element[n, Integers]], ...}.
In other words the list contains families of functions.
How to "manually" select values that lie between 3 and 5 or greater than 7, i.e. satisfy certain condition?

For the example of ConditionalExpression[2*n, Element[n, Integers]], what would you like as the output?

ConditionalExpression[2*n, Element[n, Integers]] > 5 should give ConditionalExpression[2*n, n>3]

You could try Reduce@(ConditionalExpression[2*n, Element[n, Integers]] > 5) which returns Element[n, Integers] && n >= 3. Is it critical to retain the ConditionalExpression?

Yes, it should be like Filter.

What is Filter? I am not familiar with that command.

There is no such command. I mean Filter should return list filtered according to some condition. So COnditionalExpression should be retained.

But your answer to the first comment wasn't just filtering, it was also transforming. You've also changed the semantic of the ConditionalExpression because n is no longer required to be an integer.

Are you asking how to transform a ConditionalExpression (and by extension a list of them) by updating the conditions?

Lericr, sorry, I meant Element[n, Integers] && n>=3.

You can always pass these objects into Reduce or Solve:
expr = ConditionalExpression[Pi*n + Pi/2, Element[n, Integers]];

Reduce[3 < expr < 5, n, Integers]


n == 1


Reduce[expr > 7, n, Integers]


n ∈ Integers && n >= 2


